# Lightweight frameworks for client-side MVC in javascript?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I'm building a simple client-side survey tool. Users create and edit short surveys and export them as XML (or something similar) when they're done.

I started off using jquery, but realized that it was going to be a headache to map back and forth between the HTML DOM and the underlying XML. It's easy to edit one or the other, but keeping them in sync is a pain.

Anyway, this seems like a standard MVC problem, with a few extra wrinkles:

- I want to do all this work clientside.
- Lightweight is definitely better.

Any thoughts? I looked into backbone, but it seems to be build around REST-ful interactions with a server-side model, which doesn't work well for me. JavascriptMVC looked really bulky for something this small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have a look at [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com), which is a JavaScript MVVM framework, which lends itself very well to what your doing.

You can use jQuery to turn the xml into JavaScript objects and add a little Knockout model magic and your UI will automatically update itself when the model changes.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) which states that it brings to HTML what is required to use HTML for JS driven web applications. You can find a simple example of it's usage in form of a showcase of a very simple todo application on the starting page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Backbone without server sync by creating your custom storage backend providing in-memory persistence

Look at a sample localStorage backend: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html which overrides Backbone's sync method

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a true "MVC" framework, but you may benefit from checking out the jQuery template plugin - http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/ .  You can create a template (in this case could be the XML template) that you can use to build the output from a JSON object.  This would allow you to maintain the data in one place and allow the "rendering" to happen automatically from your data object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScriptMVC via it's download builder:  http://javascriptmvc.com/builder.html.  Just check the model, view, controller and you are off!  Here's a walkthrough of using just those parts:

http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!mvc